# AngularJS - remove duplicate records

Tags: angularjs

I am really new to the world of angularjs and I am working on angular 1.5

What I am trying to do is remove the duplicate records from the response before assigning it to the `$scope`

The results that i get looks like as following

```
[
{
    "phoneNumbers": [
      {
        "value": "00 1 111-222-333",
        "pref": false,
        "id": 0,
        "type": null
      },
      {
        "value": "00 1 222-222-333",
        "pref": false,
        "id": 1,
        "type": null
      },
      {
        "value": "00 1 333-222-333",
        "pref": false,
        "id": 2,
        "type": null
      }
    ]
  },{
    "phoneNumbers": [
      {
        "value": "00 1 111-222-333",
        "pref": false,
        "id": 0,
        "type": null
      },
      {
        "value": "00 1 222-222-333",
        "pref": false,
        "id": 1,
        "type": null
      },
      {
        "value": "00 1 333-222-333",
        "pref": false,
        "id": 2,
        "type": null
      }
    ]
  }]
```

You will notice that there are 2 arrays and both have sub array called `phoneNumbers` and they have the exact same value.

What I need is if `phoneNumbers` of any array matches the `phoneNumbers` of another array then remove that array all together from the response.

I will really appreciate any help on this.

[image]

Comment: You mean an array of two objects.

Comment: @rrd i have attached an image of how my response looks like

Comment: @Weedoze  i have attached an image of how my response looks like

Comment: I think that is simpler to do this computation on the server side rather than on the client. In such a way you have more computational power on the server and the payload of the response is smaller, so less data to transfer means more transfer speed.

Comment: @GabrieleCiech believe me I want to do that but in this case, i have been told to do it on client.

Comment: @Saadia Phonenumber matching is when all the 4 properties are the same ?

Comment: @Weedoze they are not going to be 4 all the time, some times it might just be 1 or 2, as long as they match.

Comment: @Saadia As long as what matchs ? Only the value ?

Comment: @Weedoze yes, only the value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

This is not angularjs question, but rather general question of comparing objects and arrays. You can find good example in the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript